# Get Key for object created after Push (Angular and Firebase)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm having problems understanding how to use Firebase. I wrote a function to push some data in my firebase database. I need to get the Key generated after I push the data into my db.

This is my function

```
  postData(order: orderInfo) {
    let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.db.list('transactions').push({
      currency: order.currency,
      total: order.total,
      rate: order.rate,
      uid: uid
    });
    console.log(order.$key);
    this.db.list('transactionsPerUser').update(uid, order.$key);
  }
```

When I push the data to transactions path, it also pushes user uid so I can link the data from my user database to transactions database. What I want now is to link in other part of my database the transactions made by users, something like this:

```
transactionsPerUser {
     user1 {
           order.$key (key generated by push) : "true"
                     }
            {
```

As you can see, I'm trying to console.log(order.$key) but it returns undefined. How can I solve this?? and second, is this a proper way to structure my database? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a small change to the post line and add / to the transactions

```
postData(order: orderInfo) {
    let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

// Change this next line to save the transaction

    var newRef = this.db.list('/transactions').push({
      currency: order.currency,
      total: order.total,
      rate: order.rate,
      uid: uid
    });

// get just the key reference
var newKey= newRef.key;

//then change this refer

    console.log(newKey);

//To update you would change the next line

    this.db.list('transactionsPerUser').update(newKey, order.newInfo);
}
```

Comment: And to get the key later from an object from the list you can call order.$key

Comment: Hi Gavin. Thanks for your help. Im getting this error in the console now Firebase.update failed: "First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace."

Comment: This is how I do an update on a field, please note name is the type of field and you need to give name a value first   if(this.order.name){
        this.db.list('transactionsPerUser').update(newKey,
        {name : this.name }); 
        }

Comment: Since you are from 2 different lists, please don't forget to ensure you get the right key reference for the right list

Comment: You missed some steps but it helped me anyway so I marked your answer as correct. This is what was missing `var newKey= newRef.key;
    var keyTrans = {};
    keyTrans[newKey] = true;
    console.log(newKey);
    this.db.list('transactionsPerUser').update(uid, keyTrans);`